# Vocabulary words

Tags: vocabulary

I wonder if anyone can explain me the difference between "word" and "vocabulary word". Does "vocabulary word" mean words of a particular language? When do we use "word" or "vocabulary word"?

Answer (score 1):

A vocabulary word is just a word that is part of some vocabulary: a given set of words known to a given set of people. The words you know are your vocabulary, and the words in your vocabulary are your vocabulary words.